# How to create user with user UID in database? Is there a trigger event once user is sign up?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Once a user is sign-in, I would like to add the user to the firebase database:

[image]
e.g.:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "testUserUID1" : {
      "username" : "User 1",
      "phoneNumber" : "+611111111",
    }
   }
}
```

Is there a trigger event once the user is signed up, so that I can pump in the data to the db?

e.g.

```
functions.database.ref('/???/{userId}/???').onWrite((event) => {

});
```

I do not want to use the completion event on the client side to send the user uid to the database to create a user (there's a chance for the user device to be disconnected when passing the user uid back to the database)

Answer (score 0):

seems like there's auth event:

```
functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {

    const user = event.data;

    var userObject = {
        displayName : user.displayName,
        email : user.email,
        photoUrl : user.photoURL,
        createdOn : user.metadata.createdAt
    };
    admin.database().ref('users/' + user.uid).set(userObject);
});
```

Comment: Note that the trigger function parameters changed with `firebase-functions` v1.0.0.  Details in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#authentication).

Comment: got it thanks @BobSnyder. The documentation helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for making changes in your Firebase Database:

DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()

And then run the function:
myRef.child("users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("username").setValue();

This will create a reference into your database and create children as specified in 'child()' and then saves the value by 'setValue();'.

Best of luck ;)